# for loop long dataframe format, for loop per grouped variable and output to new dataframe

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, spatial

I have a long format dataframe which has four columns with livelihoodzones, periods of measurement, observation values and forecasted values. I want to do some statistics over these columns per livelihood zone. I already ordered the livelihood zones alphabetically, as I thought this might help me. After this I thought about a for loop, which would go over the first same set of livelihood zones and will do so for the entire length of the dataframe. But it's not performing as I hope it would. So my question is how can you tell the for loop that it should do its first loop and the ones after over a fixed amount of rows?

Let me know if you want me to produce a REPREX or I need to clarify something! Many thanks!

```
dfUG_abc <- dfUG[order(dfUG$`Livelihood zone`), ]
names_period_UG <- unique(dfUG$`Period of measurement Uganda`)
count_period_UG <- length(names_period_UG)
names_lv_UG <- unique(dfUG$`Livelihood zone`)
count_lv_UG <- length(names_lv_UG)
Spatial_lv_UG <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = count_lv_UG))
colnames(Spatial_lv_UG) <- c("names", "bias", "RMSE", "accuracy")
Spatial_lv_UG[,1] <- names_lv_UG
Spatial_lv_UG <- Spatial_lv_UG[order(Spatial_lv_UG$names),]


for (i in 1:count_lv_UG){
  Spatial_lv_UG[i,3]<-hydroGOF::rmse(dfUG_abc$`IPC class2`, dfUG_abc$`IPC class`)
  Spatial_lv_UG[i,2]<-bias(dfUG_abc$`IPC class`, dfUG_abc$`IPC class2`)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider `by` (object-oriented wrapper to `tapply`) to iterate through levels or unique values of a column and build a list of grouping data frames. Then run a `do.call` + `rbind` at end for the final, master data frame. With this approach, there is no need to initialize an empty data frame to assign rows to it or even order columns by grouping variable.

```
df_list <- by(dfUG, dfUG$`Livelihood zone`, function(sub) {
    data.frame(zone = sub$`Livelihood zone`[1],
               bias = bias(sub$`IPC class`, sub$`IPC class2`),
               RMSE = hydroGOF::rmse(sub$`IPC class2`, sub$`IPC class`), 
               accuracy = NA)
})

Spatial_lv_UG <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```

Above fills `NA` in *accuracy* column as you do not show how that column should be assigned. Adjust accordingly.